# MySQLi exits without error

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $musername, $mpass, $mdatabase);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
$sqquer = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM ? where id=?');
$sqquer->bind_param('is', $mtable, $_SESSION['User']['id']);
if ($sqquer==false) {
  echo "fail";
}
echo "<br>Test 2";
$sqquer->execute();
echo "<br>Test 3";
$sqquer->store_result();
```

This outputs none of the tests. What am I missing? I have tried changing the param function but no success, I am sure I am missing something trivial.

Comment: is your table name is of interger type

Comment: Are you actually defining $musername, $mpass, $mdatabase anywhere?

Comment: Check if you mysqli extension is loaded in php.ini.
If its not, enable it. Also make sure error reporting is enabled so that you see errors.

Comment: What do you get if you add `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` to the top of your script?

Comment: Simple, table names cant be prepared. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement, also is your table name an integer?

Comment: l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇ ƇhƐȓ0nè answered the question, Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure mysqli is enabled?

Check php.ini and uncomment (ie remove ;) this line....

```
;mysqli.dll
```

To...

```
mysqli.dll   (mysqli.so on linux)
```