# oracle exception: invalid table name

Tags: java, oracle, servlets, jdbc

I am using `JDBC` for connecting to the database (Oracle10) in Servlets.
Following is my query in which I want to set the three parameters dynamically.

1. Table name
2. Column name
3. Value

Query:

```
query = "select ? from ? where ? = ?";
mypstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
mypstmt.setString(1, tableName);
mypstmt.setString(2, columnName);
mypstmt.setString(3, columnName2);
mypstmt.setString(4, value);
```

But above query is giving me error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

I checked the table name. it is correct, and if I write the query like:

```
query = "select "+columnName+" from "+tableName+" where "+columnName2+" = ?";
```

Then it is executing fine.

So what should I do if I want to set the `Table name` and `Column Names` as `mypstmt.setString(1,tableName)`

**Edit1**
The reason why I want to `parameterize` the `Table name` and `Column name` is that I am allowing user to Select/Enter Table names and column names, so I want to avoid `SQL Injection`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't pass the tablename directly to `PreparedStatement` as table name cannot be a bind variable . [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

> **An object that represents a precompiled SQL statement.**
>
> A SQL statement is precompiled and stored in a PreparedStatement object. This object can then be used to efficiently execute this statement multiple times.

You have to construct the sql with string concatenation. Using Stored Procedure , you can pass table name dynamically using [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). Even look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327831/1163607) to understand why it is restricted.

Comment: Column names can be passed as parameters using `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: @Polppan - no.  Only values can be passed as parameters.  (Otherwise, the SQL engine would not be able to precompile/plan prepared statements, and you'd have more scope for injection attacks, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

you can only parameterized `?` column value in SQL query. Table/Column parametrizing is not possible, instead use variable to construct such query, for example :

```
void query(String tableName, String columnName, String queryColumnName String val) {
String query = "select "+columnName+" from "+tableName+" where "+queryColumnName+" = ?";
mypstmt.setString(1, val);
..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PreparedStatement you can only replace value. You cann't replace tablename, or column name.