# In the Python package "Exscript.protocols" , how can I pass a calling function parameter inside "execute()"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My function definition looks something like this:

```
def chk_table(table_name):
    .......
    .......
    conn.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name ;')
    print("The response for query : SELECT * FROM table_name; === ",repr(conn.response) )
    return
```

I get the below error:

```
Exscript.protocols.exception.InvalidCommandException: Device said:
SELECT * FROM table_name;
Error: no such table: table_name
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You are hard-coding the "table_name". Duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324996/replace-table-name-with-variable-using-python-and-mysql-connector

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement (php question, but more generic answer).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace table name with variable. Using python and mysql connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324996/replace-table-name-with-variable-using-python-and-mysql-connector)