# Something's wrong with dynamic querying in my code

Tags: python, mysql-connector, dynamicquery

I'm trying to learn about python-mysql connector, and things have been going well, until I bumped into this little problem. The 3rd line in the snippet below is giving me the following error:

`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''employee' NATURAL JOIN department' at line 1`

```
       con = connector.connect(user='root',host='127.0.0.1',passwd='***',database='sqltest')
       crs = con.cursor()
       crs.execute("SELECT * FROM %s NATURAL JOIN department",("employee",))
       result = crs.fetchall()
       self.t1.setRowCount(len(result)+1)
       self.t1.setColumnCount(len(result[0]))
       self.t1.setItem(0,0,QTableWidgetItem("ID"))
```

When I replaced the statement without dynamic query, i.e `SELECT * FROM employee NATURAL JOIN department` , things seem to work just fine.

Hoping that somebody knows a way around this snag. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about this specific connector, but using a parameter for the table name (ie anything but data) is not usually supported.

Comment: Ah, that just might be it. Thanks for the reply brother!

Comment: Extra comma after `"employee"` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's needed when you're defining a tuple with a single element.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324996/replace-table-name-with-variable-using-python-and-mysql-connector