# create tables with String array in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

First, I have weak eng skill.

(Using mysql module)
I want create tables (5 tables) with same column

but i have error message that

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''pre'(       R varchar(5), Name varchar(20), Team varchar(20), Age varchar(5), Positio' at line 1

my code is here

```
post=['pre','b','c','d','e'];
conn.query('create table ?(\
    R varchar(5), Name varchar(20), Team varchar(20), Age varchar(5), Position varchar(20), Apps varchar(5), Yel varchar(5) , Red varchar(5), AerialsWon varchar(5), MotM varchar(5), \
    Tackles varchar(5), Inter varchar(5), Fouls varchar(5), Offsides varchar(5), Clear varchar(5), OwnG varchar(5),\
    Goals varchar(5),SpG varchar(5), Drb varchar(5), Fouled varchar(5), Off varchar(5), Disp varchar(5),\
    Assists varchar(5), KeyP varchar(5), AvgP varchar(5), PsR varchar(5), Crosses varchar(5),Thrb varchar(10))', post, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;     
        console.log('//2.Create pre table');
});
```

When I insert value , (? and post array ) running . but (? and post array ) don't working in table name.

Comment: You cannot parametrize table name.

Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement

Comment: thank you . I read the link. but I can't understand perfectly.  is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's impossible. But you can use string concatenation:

```
var table_name = 'pre';
var query = 'CREATE TABLE ' + table_name + '...';
```

The rest would stay as previous.