# Error in mysql query in select

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a problem, I wanted to make a query to the search form data where people insert some filters will search for products appear less in this specific case are houses.
had made a query with "or" does not work as well as this it makes the fields alone, and "and" not also works because I do not want users to fill out all the fields, so is the they want, so I did it

```
$texto = array();
$contador=0;

if($_SESSION["finalidade"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[1]="`finalidade` LIKE ".$finalidade;}

if($_SESSION["tipoimovel"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[2]="`tipoimovel` LIKE ".$tipoimovel;}

if($_SESSION["nquarto"]!=0){
    $contador++;
    $texto[3]="`nquartos` = ".$nquarto;}

if($_SESSION["pmin"]!=0){
    $contador++;
    $texto[4]="`preco` > ".$pmin;}

if($_SESSION["pmax"]!=0){
    $contador++;
    $texto[5]="`preco` < ".$pmax;}

if($_SESSION["elevador"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[6]="`elevador` LIKE ".$elevador;}

if($_SESSION["garagem"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[7]="`garagem` LIKE ".$garagem;}

if($_SESSION["vistapriv"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[8]="`vistapreveligiada` LIKE ".$vistapriv;}

if($_SESSION["piscina"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[9]="`piscina` LIKE ".$piscina;}

if($_SESSION["jardim"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[10]="`jardim` LIKE ".$jardim;}

if($_SESSION["condominiof"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[11]="`condominio` LIKE ".$condominiof;}

if($_SESSION["conselho"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[12]="`conselho` LIKE ".$conselho;}

if($_SESSION["frequesia"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[13]="`frequesia` LIKE ".$frequesia;}

if($_SESSION["refimovel"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[14]="`referencia` LIKE ".$refimovel;}

    $textocompleto="";


$contador2=1;

for($y = 0; $y < 16; $y++) {

    if($texto[$y]!=""){
        if($contador2==1 && $contador2!=$contador){
            $contador2++;
            ;
        $textocompleto=$texto[$y]." AND ";  }
        elseif($contador2==$contador){
            $contador2++;

        $textocompleto=$textocompleto.$texto[$y];}
        elseif($contador2==1 && $contador2==$contador){
            $contador2++;

        $textocompleto=$texto[$y];  }
        else {
            $contador2++;

        $textocompleto=$textocompleto.$texto[$y]." AND ";}



    }



}

$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ID, imagem, frequesia ,conselho, preco FROM `imovel` WHERE ?  ORDER BY `imovel`.`preco` DESC LIMIT ?,? ");
$results->bind_param("sii",$textocompleto,  $page_position, $item_per_page);
$results->execute();
$results->bind_result($id ,$imagem, $frequesia ,$conselho, $preco); //bind variables to prepared statement
}
```

the problem is that it is not me to return anything, does not show me any value.
already do not know what else to do because if you make a if for each of the possibilities will give more than 100 if and will take a long time.
if anyone knows of some effective and quick way to do this please help me, because in fact not know what else to do to fix this problem, thank you

Comment: Firstly, did you start the session? Then you have 2x (valid) `?` but 3 in your binds. You're not checking for errors here. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Plus, you can't bind columns `WHERE ?` and checking for errors would have told you about that. Which is why it's failing.

Comment: yeah i start  
session_start();
$muda=$_SESSION["muda"] ;
i have 3 ? 
WHERE ? 
LIMIT ?,? ");

Comment: do a "echo" on the prepare("SELECT...") with the bind variables and the put the output in your SQL Database. Thats how you get a right Error message. Try it.

Comment: ahh, my fear was even this ... and have any idea how phaco this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement

Comment: what do you mean? sorry I did not realize what to do

Comment: you can't bind tables/columns as per my link above. Plus, what is the value of `$finalidade`? is it a string or an integer?

Comment: did you try to ouput your MySQLi Statement?

Comment: It would surprise me if you could pass a WHERE condition as a parameter. I also don't see why you'd use unsafe stringification first and then use a parameter; if you don't care about safety, just concat your complete text and prepare that. However, I would suggest adding both a string and an object in the ifs (also, I'd just put them in the next free slot instead of a fixed one), so `$texto[$contador] = "'column' like ?"; $parametro[$contador] = $column; $contador++;`

Comment: @Zastai  you said like that 
´if($_SESSION["finalidade"]!=""){
    $contador++;
    $texto[1]="`finalidade` LIKE ?";
    $parametro[1] = $column; $contador++;
}´

Comment: @IgorPonte No, use contador to index the arrays. That makes them easier to process afterwards.

Comment: You can exemplifies? not realized

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind parts of an SQL statement, you can only bind values.

So this is valid:

```
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl WHERE col3 = ?");
$results->bind_param("i", 1234);
```

and this is not:

```
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl WHERE ?");
$results->bind_param("s", "col3 = 1234");
```

You can concatenate the strings, though:

```
prepare("SELECT ... WHERE ".$textocompleto." ORDER BY imovel.preco DESC LIMIT ?,? ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prefix on your `$\_SESSION` variable like `sf_{variable_name}` for all required fields. After that, you can loop throughout them to build your query
`(ps : code not tested)`:

```
$sql = "SELECT ";
$sql_cond = " WHERE ";
$texto = [];
foreach($_SESSION as $k => $v){
    if(substr($v, 0, 3) == "sf_"){
        $name = substr($k, 3, strlen($k))
        $texto[$name] = $v;
        $sql .= $name.", ";
        $sql_cond .= $name." LIKE :".$name;
    }
}
$final_sql = $sql.$sql_cond;
$results = $mysqli->prepare($final_sql);
foreach($texto as $k => $v){
    $results->bind_param(":".$k, "%".$v."%");
}
$results->execute();
```

Ok, after some tests, i did the same with PDO object in a test db for medias (PDO is nearly the same stuff than MYSQLI object), and it work fine for me, just adapt your db ids for your case

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=media_center', 'root', 'root');

$_SESSION["sf_title"] = "Interstellar";
$_SESSION["sf_description"] = "sci-fi";

$sql = "SELECT * ";
$sql_cond = " WHERE ";
$texto = [];

foreach($_SESSION as $k => $v){
    if(substr($k, 0, 3) == "sf_"){
        $name = substr($k, 3, strlen($k));
        $texto[$name] = $v;
        $sql_cond .= $name." LIKE :".$name." OR ";
    }
}

$sql_cond = substr($sql_cond, 0, strlen($sql_cond)-4);
$final_sql = $sql." FROM media ".$sql_cond;
$results = $pdo->prepare($final_sql);

foreach($texto as $k => $v){
    $key = ":".$k;
    $value = "%".$v."%";
    $results->bindParam($key, $value);
}

$results->execute();
```

Comment: this code give me one error "Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object"  can you help me pls?

Comment: can you put this code inside my code pls for i see what i do wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you will need to wrap the values in single qoute `''`

For example:

```
$texto[1]="`finalidade` LIKE ".$finalidade;
```

should be

```
$texto[1]="`finalidade` LIKE '".$finalidade."'";
```

Try this.. I think it will solve it

Comment: if `$finalidade` is an integer, then their code is valid/correct.

Comment: @IgorPonte you didn't respond to an important question earlier. What is the value of `$finalidade`? is it a string or an integer? string = "city" integer = `123`

Comment: @IgorPonte then their answer here is wrong and I had a feeling it was from the beginning.

Comment: Did you put the single qoutes in all the condition?

Comment: yes and go completing the measure that you go filling

Comment: Instead of the `foreach` , try `$textocompleto = implode(' AND ',$texto)`