# Preparing a query with mysqli_stmt_prepare binding a logical criteria after WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I need to dynamically launch queries based on filters which change over time. Every time the filter is in the string variable **`$filter`**.
Am I allowed to bind it after `WHERE` like in the following code? It doesn't seem to work. The resulting query I expect is `SELECT NAME FROM PERSONA WHERE GENDER='F'`

```
$filter = "GENDER='F'";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT NAME FROM PERSONA WHERE ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $filter);
```

Comment: That's an odd way to bind.  I would expect to see `WHERE GENDER = ?`, and you would bind `F` to that parameter...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I parameterize the table name in a prepared statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement)

Comment: ^ which also applies to columns.

Comment: The idea is that $filter may change and does not always refer to GENDER: it may be CITY='NY' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind values, not syntactic elements. So either keep the `gender` condition and just bind the `F` value:

```
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT NAME FROM PERSONA WHERE GENDER=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', 'F');
```

Or use string manipulation to construct the query:

```
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT NAME FROM PERSONA WHERE $filter");
```

Answer (score -1):

The other answer is obviously wrong. As the first suggestion doesn't answer the question at all, and the second one would work only for gender. While even for a CITY would be just impossible.

So you will have to create your query dynamically.
[With mysqli it's too toilsome](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison#in) so I'll show how to do that with PDO:

```
$sql = "SELECT NAME FROM PERSONA WHERE 1";
$filters = [];
$params = []
if ($gender)
{
    $filters[] = " AND GENDER=:gender";
    $params['gender'] = $gender;
}
$sql .= implode("", $filters);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```