# Prepared Statement Param working once

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

**Hi,**

I'm working on a small project and I like the Query to check something for me. However for that I need to select something which is also needed in the WHERE clause.

```
// Prepare Query
$sql = "SELECT ? FROM permissions WHERE (req = ? AND single_delete = '1')";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

// Bind Parameters and execute.
$stmt->bind_param("si", $action, $user['permissions']);
$stmt->execute();

// Store result and make it a variable.
$stmt->store_result();
$permissioncount = $stmt->num_rows;

return $permissioncount;
```

Like this it's working. It returns the correct count. However as soon as I change `single_delete` to the variable `$action`, it will return `0`. The variable `$action` contains `single_delete`. My Question is, why isn't it possible or what am I doing wrong?

**The code**

```
    // Prepare Query
$sql = "SELECT ? FROM permissions WHERE (req = ? AND ? = '1')";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

// Bind Parameters and execute.
$stmt->bind_param("sis", $action, $user['permissions'], $action);
$stmt->execute();

// Store result and make it a variable.
$stmt->store_result();
$permissioncount = $stmt->num_rows;

return $permissioncount;
```

Comment: You cannot use bound parameters for the table or column names in a prepared query

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that. What is the best way to get the same effect of the code I need?

Comment: You will have to concatenate the names when you build `$sql` like this `$sql = "SELECT $action  FROM permissions WHERE (req = ? AND $action = '1')"` but that risks allowing an SQL Injection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I parameterize the table name in a prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11312737/1839439)