# Placing "From ?" does not work in PDO

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

Why placing a "?" in front of "FROM" does not work, while in other places it works?

```
query = "SELECT nome_cliente 
         FROM ?
         ORDER BY nome_cliente";

$rows = $this->db->prepare($query);
$rows->execute([$id]);
```

The error it gives is this:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? ORDER BY nome_cliente' at line 1
```

Comment: This should not work.  Specify the table

Comment: Show the code of where it works

Comment: it only works if I put the variable directly in the query, like so: query = "SELECT nome_cliente 
         FROM $id
         ORDER BY nome_cliente"; but like this is prone to sql injection

Comment: Basicly placeholder are for **values** NOT for creating **sql syntax**. Use  them only for **values**. Here read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement#11327831

Comment: @LuísAlves, why are you accepting a table name from users in the first place?

Comment: @Chris the table is defined by the user by choosing in a drop down selection. This sets a global variable.

Comment: Ok got it guys/girls, can't placehold table names. Will sanitize manually.

Comment: This is one reason not to have lots of identical tables.