# How use Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query with MySQL

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm using Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query

```
query = " select id from $1 where id = $2 "
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo, query, [table, id])
```

But the adapter not replace my table as parameter

```
[debug] QUERY ERROR db=0.5ms
 select id from $1 where sysid = $2  ["activities", "469601326"]
[info] Application dgtidx exited: Docomo.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Docomo.Consumer
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (Mariaex.Error) (1146): Table 'test.$1' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a parameter to specify the table name like that as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327831/320615).

If you're **absolutely sure** `table` is a valid table name and not arbitrary user input, you can use string interpolation:

```
query = "select id from #{table} where id = $1"
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo, query, [id])
```

You must ensure `table` is not arbitrary user input if you do this or you'll open yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: It's a string, i validate this value. But, are there a way to sanitize it?

Comment: I'd create a whitelist of table names and check against that: `if table in ["posts", "comments"] do .... query ... else ... show error ... end`.