# password_verify() doesnt work when fetch from database

Tags: php

What wrong with my code? please need some help cause I dont see any problem. but still password_verify doesnt work.

```
public function login($username, $password){
    global $db;
    $sql = 'SELECT id,password FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'admin WHERE username="'.$username.'"';
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $pass = $row['password'];
    if (password_verify($password,$pass)) {
        echo "Valid";
    }else{
        echo "Invalid";
    }
}
```

This is the password hashing and then save to DB

```
public function addnewadmin($username,$password)
{

    global $db;
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO admin (username, password) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$hash."')";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    return true;

}
```

Comment: What is `$row` ? Also, please use prepared statements, you're vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: sorry I forgot to paste   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

Comment: I already editted the posted code

Comment: And please show the code that generates the hash too? also, do you modify $password at all between the request and `login`?

Comment: Take password, hash it and compare with value in database __visually__.

Comment: is `$password` hashed the same way it is in DB?

Comment: I editted the post adding how it was hashed and saved to DB

Comment: But you don't fetch it ?

Comment: @u_mulder ive done it already

Comment: try with PASSWORD_BCRYPT password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

Comment: How does it fail, does it just send "invalid" for every request? Where does the "id" column come from - is that an AUTO_INCREMENT? What's the DB_PREFIX value doing there, it's not in your INSERT statement? BTW, please add the MYSQL tag if that's the database you're using.

Comment: @julesR I fetched it in the function login(), the value of $pass is the hashed value from the DB

Comment: yes it echos "invalid" and yes the id is just auto increment, I am sorry for the mistake in my post this is just my first post here.

Comment: Just checking, what's the database definition of your `password` column?

Comment: Please post the code for your login() function. Try setting ```display errors``` see http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php so you'll get any error messages sent to your browser.

Comment: @JonStirling varchar(255)

Comment: Can't see anything wrong then. My only suggestion is that maybe something is changing the password string somehow somewhere between the request and getting into one or both of these methods.

Comment: I tried, echo "$password" and echo "$pass" , but it really shows the expected result just the password_verify() always returning "invalid"

Comment: You are inserting into `admin` and reading from `<DB_PREFIX>admin`. If DB_PREFIX is non-null, then they are different tables.

Comment: What is the length of your password field?

Comment: @McBern its varchar(255), I am using Mysql Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this properly.

First, use prepared statements to get rid of SQL injection:

```
$stmt = 'SELECT id,password FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'admin WHERE username = ?';
$stmt->execute($username);
```

Then, and I guess that was the problem, **fetch** the result.

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$pass = $row['password'];
```

And now, you can verify the password.

Comment: `FROM ? admin` ?

Comment: Sure, though `FROM ?` won't always work. identifiers aren't generally allowed to use placeholders.

Comment: Does not work in [pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter) nor [mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement)

Comment: I changed it already but still not working, when i tried to echo $pass it returns the value from the db