# mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have below Query in my Php, it outputs result but at the same time giving an error `mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string` what is wrong in below code

```
 $con = @mysqli_connect("localhost","$dbname","$dbpass","$dbuser");

 if (!$con)
 {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 $sql_uid=$con->prepare("SELECT id From $dtUsi Where mobile_number='$umobile' and user_type='$user_type'");

 $stmti = $con->query($sql_uid);

 while($rowi = $stmti->fetch_assoc()) {
 $ur_id= $rowi['id'];
 }
 echo $ur_id;
```

Comment: You have already prepared the SQL (although not effectively as you still substitute all of the values in the SQL), you then need to `execute()` and not run `query()`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use prepare and query at the same time. You are giving `$sql_uid` to `query` function like it's a query string while it isn't. Use one the these approaches.

Either

```
$con = @mysqli_connect("localhost","$dbname","$dbpass","$dbuser");

 if (!$con)
 {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 $stmti=$con->query("SELECT id From $dtUsi Where mobile_number='$umobile' and user_type='$user_type'");

 while($rowi = $stmti->fetch_assoc()) {
 $ur_id= $rowi['id'];
 }
 echo $ur_id;
```

or

```
$con = @mysqli_connect("localhost","$dbname","$dbpass","$dbuser");

 if (!$con)
 {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 $stmti=$con->prepare("SELECT id From $dtUsi Where mobile_number='?' and user_type='?'");
 $stmt->bind_param("ss", $umobile, $user_type);

 $stmt->execute();
 while($rowi = $stmti->fetch_assoc()) {
 $ur_id= $rowi['id'];
 }
 echo $ur_id;
```

These links might be helpful:

[PHP MySQL Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

[Select Data With MySQLi](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Comment: Although it's useful to post both methods as it explains how `query()` should be used.  It's always worth highlighting that using prepared statements properly is the way to do it (although you can't bind the table name in a prepared statement - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement).

Comment: Yes you're right, thanks for comment I edited the table name. Of course yes.