# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '17'

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, database-connection, node-mssql

Using [mssql](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#readme)(6.3.1) and node(14.15.1).

Query works when I use the template literal as shown in the documentation.

This was my query within template literal and it works. (DB names aren't variables here)

```
await sql.query`
    INSERT
      INTO
      DB.DB.notes (updated_date,
      updated_user,
      note_description,
      work_order_id,
      created_date ,
      created_user)
    values(
    ${normalizedDate},
    ${username} ,
    ${note_description},
    ${wo_id},
    ${normalizedDate} ,
    ${username} )
`;
```

But when I try to replace the DB with variables let's say `${DB}`, it is throwing error.
First it was saying

> RequestError: Incorrect syntax near "."

and after that I got

> RequestError: Incorrect syntax near "17" (it started from 14 and it's incremented to 17)

This is the [documentation](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#readme), and I have tried a `ConnectionPool` class, `.query('/**query**/')`, but none worked for me.

Please suggest what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're using in your query generates a parameterised query.

It is not possible to paramaterise "identifiers" in queries. See [Can I parameterize the table name in a prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement)

Comment: you're right, I found a workaround to it.