# Using tablenames as argument in execute prepared statement

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Working in the query-box of phpMyAdmin I want to write an outfile 'protokoll' for each table in a MySQL 5.5 database. As I have many databases that contain the same tables and are different by name only, I want the filename of the outfile to look like
/tmp/dbname_protokoll_tablename_.csv

This works:

```
SELECT DATABASE() into @client;
SET @dir = '/tmp/';
SET @table = 'Adressen';
SET @stmt = CONCAT( 'SELECT * from ', @table, ' WHERE MarkDel=1 into outfile ''', @dir, @client , '_Protokoll_', @table , '.csv'' CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '','' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ''"'' LINES TERMINATED BY ''\r\n'' ');
PREPARE DoExport from @stmt;
EXECUTE DoExport;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE DoExport;
```

From what I read about prepare, I should be able to use a '?' inside the statement, like

```
SET @stmt = CONCAT( 'SELECT * from ? WHERE MarkDel=1 into outfile ...
```

and then execute this with a list of arguments like

```
EXECUTE DoExport USING 'Adressen', 'Familien', 'Kinder';
```

but I can't get this to work, all I receive is an unspecific syntax error. How do I have to rewrite this?

Comment: You can´t use prepared statements placeholders for table or column names, only for values

Comment: @nacho ... for values and as LIMIT parameters.

Comment: Damn, that's the answer I feared. Is there another way to acchieve this?

Comment: @Akina limit parameters are also values.

Comment: achieve *what*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I parameterize the table name in a prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f684f00775da068161f4aabd313101b

Comment: @Akina Yes, what is your point? Nacho said parameters can only be used for values, you then replied "[..] and as LIMIT parameters". Given limit parameters **are** values, that distinction doesn't make much sense, hence my reply.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In the query, not in prepared statement, LIMIT parameters are LITERALS (like database/table/column names), not values. Like database/table/column names, LIMIT parameters may be parametrized via prepared statement only.

Comment: @Akina Prepared statements are the only place where you can have parameters

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Values allows expressions. Literal values are treated as-is.

Comment: @Akina database/table/column names are called identifiers not literals. and limit parameters are definitely not identifiers, but as you rightfully called them, [literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/literals.html), just like other strings and numbers

Comment: @Akina Database column names, etc are not literals, they are identifiers. Literals are values, just like parameters are (placeholders for) values.