# Pass parameter in jdbc request in jmeter

Tags: sql-server, select, parameters, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

In jdbc request, I have query where table name should be passed as parameter

Select * from '${b1}'

Below in jdbc request I have
Parameter values as tablename1
Variable names as b1

But after executing query I am getting an error - incorrect syntax near '${b1}'

Answer (score 0):

1. [You cannot use a table or database name in a prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement)
2. Even if it would be valid you should modify your SQL query to look like:

   ```
   select * from ?
   ```

So instead of using "Parameter values" in the JDBC Request sampler you should set the variable using i.e. [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) and amend your SQL query to look like:

```
select * from b1
```

and JMeter in the runtime will substitute `${b1}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) placeholder with its respective value:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Select * from '${b1}' use Select * from ${b1} in your JDBC sample request.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).